# Can't flash Ubuntu to my Galaxy Nexus: "device is unsupported". What can I do?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm attempting to flash the Ubuntu for phone os onto my Galaxy Nexus, but after typing in the command `phablet-flash -b` it says that the device is unsupported and that it was detected as being toroplus. What can I do?

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/259459/phablet-flash-detects-a-nexus-7-as-tilapia

Answer (score 0):

The Sprint Galaxy Nexus, codename toroplus, is not currently supported. At this point, only the unlocked HSPA+ Galaxy Nexus, codename maguro, is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Xda Senior Member kdb424 made it bootable on the Galaxy Nexus Toroplus. I did it to mine and it worked fine, but i will stress that it is only bootable, nothing but wifi and camera really work on it. But the porting guide was released today so we'll probably be seeing a lot more options here soon. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2159832